# Installing fpdf in Yii vendor

Tags: php, yii, fpdf

I am trying to work with fpdf class in yii. So I import the total fpdf folder in yii vendor folder then tried to import in view file like:

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
```

then just paste a class as follows

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

But that ends up with a error as "This pdf document might not be displayed correctly. And if I try to download and view then it says
"File type HTML document (text/html) is not supported". I added 
"header('Content-Type: application/pdf');" on the view file with no help.

can anyone help?

Comment: You did not autoload library completely. Do you need FPDF or MPDF also would work?

Comment: i need FPDF to work with.i am new to yii. can you please help with the procedure?

Comment: Can you send link to which FPDF package did you download?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my recommendations.

First, follow this instructions and start using composer in your project.
http://main.org.ua/yii1-composer/

It is future, it's worth to learn it.

Then, install this package using composer https://packagist.org/packages/itbz/fpdf

And you are done.

No more manual includes or troubles with custom autoloaders.